# How can I set a special alternate landscape view to appear only for one VC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape-portrait, alternate

I created a portrait view and an alternate landscape view for my NLViewController subclass.  When I rotate the device to landscape from any other of my VC subclasses, this alternate landscape view appears for all of my other view controller subclasses.  How do I include a statement that ONLY shows this alternate landscape view when NLVIewController is called?

```
-(void)orientationDidChanged: (NSNotification *)notification {
    UIDeviceOrientation devOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(devOrientation)) {
        UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        LandscapeController *landscape = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"landscape"];
        [self presentViewController:landscape animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(devOrientation)) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I could solve this if I could figure out how to write code that says: "if device is rotated to landscape AND the UIStoryboard is at "Main_iPhone" AND the current View Controller is called "NLViewController". . ."

Comment: I think I could solve this if I could figure out how to write code that says: "if device is rotated to landscape AND the UIStoryboard is at "Main_iPhone" AND the current View Controller is called "NLViewController". . ."  It seems simple, but I've tried: UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] && currentViewController == NLViewController]; . . .along with several other attempts.

Comment: I think I solved it.  I added:  UIViewController *NLViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
and then added:
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(devOrientation) && [UIViewController isEqual:NLViewController])            Is this the most optimal way of doing this?

Comment: Wasn't the solution.  That code removed the special alternate landscape view I created and simply rotated and stretched out my portrait view in landscape.